# Tomcat 7.0.55 APR connector 8443 works but change to 443 does not

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, jira, confluence, lets-encrypt

I have multiple Digital Ocean servers and I have Confluence running with HTTPS and a Letsencrypt cert. I stood up a Debian 8 server for JIRA as well and did the HTTPS of the Apache Portable Runtime Native Tomcat the same way for this server as I did for the Confluence one but have failed using many configurations.

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.55 and Java 1.8.0_51 (JRE for Tomcat and JIRA). I'm currently using a fullchain_and_key.p12 (PKCS12) for the cert and private key for the SSL/HTTPS connector in server.xml. I have an 8080 connector that redirects to the SSL/HTTPS connector. I can run this using 8443 for the SSL/TLS connector. I change the port from 8443 to 443 and it never works.

I can telnet-check using 8080 and 8443. I cannot when I try the 443 port for the SSL/TLS connector. Iptables is wide open by default for the DigitalOcean server and I've verified this on all my servers. And, I can telnet-check today to the Confluence server using 443.

I'm out of troubleshooting options. Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Is Tomcat running as root?

Comment: Nope, lol. That was it! I just fixed up my iptables and I have what I need. Thanks Scott.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Ports 80 and 443 are privileged i.e. only processes owned by root can access them. I added the following to iptables to resolve this. Since I'm doing this on the cheap, I opted not to use a proxy server (save money). Iptables can provide port access and port forwarding like so:

```
 sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

And then I forwarded privileged ports to Tomcat ports:

```
 sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
 sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```